# Add top margin to textarea in a div

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/3j24hrgf/1/

```
<div class="note">
    <textarea rows="4"  placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>

</div>

.note {
    background-color: green;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
textarea {
    width: 80%;
    display: block;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    resize: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: dashed 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: 'Rancho', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

I made a horizontally centered textarea in a div, but I can't seem to manipulate the vertical position. Adding a margin-top will push the whole div down instead of the textarea itself.

Comment: just use `padding-top` for the div...

Comment: I'd do that, but also want to understand why what I tried doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) and you could add `display: inline-block;` to `.note` to fix it.

```css
.note {
    background-color: green;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
}
textarea {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    resize: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: dashed 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family:'Rancho', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="note">
    <textarea rows="4" placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also explain, why, please?

Comment: Yeah, why is it collapsing?

Comment: [MDN Empty blocks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) - _If there is no border, padding, inline content, height, or min-height to separate a block's margin-top from its margin-bottom, then its top and bottom margins collapse._

Comment: I added `display: inline-block` to the `textarea` and that fixed it for me

Answer (score 2):

Why not add padding to `div.note`

http://jsfiddle.net/z6201kr0/

```
.note {
    background-color: green;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea {
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    resize: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: dashed 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: 'Rancho', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use two ways to fix this.. please check the below code

```
display: inline-block; /* to .note div */
margin-top:100px; /* to input textarea */
```

or

```
padding-top:100px; /* to .note div */
height:400px; /* to .note div */
```

Thanks.